# How to secure confluence site?

Tags: confluence

I am running confluence 5.5.3 on Ubuntu 16. After site setup, I found there are multiple hits coming on this site from unknown IP.

Also, I have disabled the confluence user and create a new one for confluence on VM. When I check processes by running "TOP" command I found 1 user "1001" utilizing 200% of CPU space.

```
top - 02:39:57 up 15:46,  1 user,  load average: 2.00, 2.00, 2.00
Tasks: 135 total,   1 running, 134 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  2038400 total,   237008 free,   921920 used,   879472 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  2095100 total,  2095100 free,        0 used.   920640 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 6961 1001      20   0  464636   7372   1344 S 199.0  0.4   1841:05
    1 root      20   0   37828   6028   4132 S   0.0  0.3   0:03.75 systemd
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.77 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:+
```

Please suggest how can I secure my site?

Disabled confluence user

Answer (score 0):

One common reason (common for Java apps) may be the too small Java heap forcing confluence Java VM full garbage collection.

If the user name is not displayed on the top listing, the user ID doesn't have an entry in /etc/passwd.